# Can I power down an external drive automatically when it unmounts?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, external-hdd, unmount, udisks

I know this question is answered a lot, but I couldn't find a answer that make this happen automatically. What I would like is when I unmount the last partition of the the external HDD (as it may have more than one), I would like to power down (`udisksctl power-off`) the external HDD, so I can safely remove the USB cable.

Is there a way I can write a bash script and hook it to global partition unmount event so i can check the number of partitions that are mounted on that device and if that device is a external HDD I can issue the command to power-off. Can this be done? If so how? Any reference to documentation might help me out.

This is in Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 2):

This is 7 years long story.
The problem is caused by changing internals of UDisks on upgrade from version 1 to version 2.
It is documented on LaunchPad as [bug 1067876](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1067876). I have spent a lot of time trying to determine what was wrong, but no luck.

This is a partial answer to your question, but anyway it is working solution.
I use it on my machines with spinning hard-disks and USB devices.

Personally I use one of two solutions:

- For some devices I see that Caja (MATE DE file-manager, fork of Nautilus 2.3x) still have *Safely remove drive*.

  > [image: Safely Remove Drive in Caja]

  Clicking on it results in spin-down of hard-disk and switch LED off on USB flash/SSD
- If safely remove is not shown on Caja then I manually open GNOME Disks (`gnome-disks` command), select needed drive and click *Power Off* in its interface.

  > [image: Disks button] or [image: Disks menu]

  Then HDD spins down and LED goes off.

Writing automatic script is a bit difficult task. Also you can try to search on github or somewhere else to find possible existing solutions.

Comment: Currently i'm using the gnome-disks to power down the disks. I was more looking for automated solution, thanks for you answers

Answer (score 0):

Also some half answer.

I made for my backup harddrive a desktop starter.

```
cat bin/Backup-Platte-umount.sh 
#!/bin/bash
#devicenodes finden 
devname=$(findmnt | grep media | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -v 'sda|sdb')  
export dev=$(findmnt | grep media | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -v 'sda|sdb' | sed 's/.$//' | head -n1)
#backup-platte umounten
umount $devname && notify-send 'Backup-Platte raus' &&  udisksctl power-off -b $dev
```

I'll try to explain. I'm not very good in that.

```
devname=$(findmnt | grep media | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -v 'sda|sdb')
```

This searchs for mountet filesystem in media. My 2 internal disks are filterd out with `egrep -v 'sda|sdb'`

the next part export the a Variable.

```
export dev=$(findmnt | grep media | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -v 'sda|sdb' | sed 's/.$//' | head -n1

Gives me the pur harddrive node for udisksctl power-off 

findmnt | grep media | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -v 'sda|sdb' | sed 's/.$//' | head -n1
/dev/sdc
```

and so it works.

```
bash -x bin/Backup-Platte-umount.sh 
++ findmnt
++ grep media
++ awk '{print $2}'
++ egrep -v 'sda|sdb'
+ devname='/dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc2'
++ findmnt
++ grep media
++ awk '{print $2}'
++ egrep -v 'sda|sdb'
++ sed 's/.$//'
++ head -n1
+ export dev=/dev/sdc
+ dev=/dev/sdc
+ umount /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdc2
+ notify-send 'Backup-Platte raus'
+ udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdc
```

Note I only test it with bash as shell