# Power off vs. "safely eject" or "unmount" of external devices (cameras, (android) smartphones, externally powered hdd's, etc)?

Tags: usb, mount, android, external-hdd, unmount

<sub>*Title says it all pretty much; I would strongly assume this question would have been answered before and therefore may well be a duplicate (a very quick google and sx check didn't find retrieve anything which said "d u p l i c a t e" in bold letters yet).*</sub>

I'm just wondering whether it's ok to simply power off an external device rather than either "safely removing" or "unmounting" first (in Ubuntu 18.04 and newer). Thanks!

Comment: The point behind "unmounting" or "safely removing" is that you have to make sure all the buffered data has been flushed ( or synced with the device) . So if you just poweroff the device via their operating systems (i.e soft poweroff ) , it would be fine because all operating systems make sure all I/O operations are done before actually shutting down the device. But if you mean a hard poweroff (e.g plugging out a HDD ) , it might cause data corruption or even in the worst case , filesystem corruption if you do this when a change in the partition table is being made.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Not sure what you mean with *"poweroff the device via their OS"* - I mean for instance powering off a connected camera (with a physical button on the camera), rather than unplugging the camera.

Comment: So that means hard poweroff. "powering off the device via their OS" simply means rebooting or shutting down via for example the Android UI not via hardware. Flushing the buffers is a software stuff , so if you halt the system via the underlying hardware , the OS and the softwares cannot do anything to prevent data loss.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/a/1169825/66509 . I prefer to power off all USB devices, and see that its LEDs are off after doing so.