# Kubuntu/Ubuntu - easy way to data loss ("Safely remove" is NOT safe!)

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, kde, data-loss

**In short**

Be careful: When you do "Safely remove" on your removable device, like USB stick, do not feel safe while removing it from the port.

**Longer story**

I was shocked last weekend when I went to my sister with a USB stick to show her some photos of mine. We've been watching them and suddenly at ~40% of the slideshow, a message started showing up saying that the TV can't read the file. The case was for the remaining 60% of the photos. Sadly we stopped. At home I checked that and indeed the rest of the files were corrupted.

I tried to replicate this several times:

1. Start copying files to the USB stick (~3.5GB of photos).
2. Wait until copy notification of 100% done.
3. Click "Safely Remove" on USB stick in KDE's Dolphin File Explorer.
4. Remove USB Stick from the port (BOOM! Data loss).

I couldn't believe that, but this behaviour is consistent. At first I was using a USB stick without a usage LED indicator, so I couldn't say if it is busy on the hardware level. Then I switched to an old Kingston USB stick with LED, and **after step 3 (Click "Safely Remove" on USB stick), the usage LED was blinking for a few more minutes**!!!

**Reason**

I've searched the net and this problem seems to be related to how Linux kernel buffers write operations to removable devices. There are suggestions out there mostly to reduce `dirty_bytes` kernel parameter value, but I think this is not a solution. Giving the user an impression that now he can safely remove the stick while in reality the copy process is in progress is a **NO GO**! KDE apparently is being given a false sign from the kernel that the copy process is completed. But it is finished only from the shell's perspective. At the point of 100% done shell notification, it has just been fully moved to write cache. Then the kernel writes it slowly at real USB stick transfer speed to true completion.

**Temporary solution**

The only solution I have found for now that works is the `sync` command. Before pulling out the USB stick, just call `sync` in the command line. That flushes all the buffers and waits until **truly done**. I confirmed that with the usage LED indicator on my Kingston stick. The LED stopped blinking right after the `sync` command returned.

**Solution**

That is my question: What is going on? Am I missing something or now every (less-experienced) Linux user shall start shuddering with fear of data loss?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1169825/66509 .

Comment: Voting to close: Piercing through the fog, this seems to be a bug report. AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker, and is the wrong place to report a bug. Please report the bug properly (`ubuntu-bug dolphin`) so it can be triaged and referred to the proper upstream project with enough detail for a developer to reproduce the problem on their test system. Then it can be fixed. Testing, Reporting Bugs, and Triaging Bugs are all community responsibilities -- volunteers to participate are welcome!

Comment: To add to the above, please do take a few minutes out of your day to report the bug properly. A bug of this nature should be made known and fixed. This may not happen without your help. This may not get fixed if it isn't reported through the proper channels. Thanks!

Comment: I have just filed a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dolphin/+bug/1904790